# How do I use for to loop over potentially-empty lines of output from egrep?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to print out blank lines in a text file but I want it to also print out numbers to see how many lines of white spaces the egrep returned by using:

```
for x in $(egrep '$^ txtfile); do echo '$x'; done
```

but this doesn't echo or return anything, is there any way I know how many blank lines the egrep command returned?

Comment: Use `grep -c` to directly retrieve a count. Don't use `for` at all here -- see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: BTW, correcting the syntax on your line while still leaving the underlying bug this question is about would make it `for x in $(egrep '^$' txtfile); do echo "$x"; done`.

Comment: ...note that the `^` (start-of-line) has to come before the `$` (end-of-line), and you need to close the single quotes around that string; also, to expand the variable `$x` in your echo, it needs to be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Simply `grep -c '^$' file`

Answer (score 2):

`for` [is the wrong tool for this job](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); the right one (if you don't want to use `grep -c` but really do want to read each line of output) is a `while read` loop, as discussed in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- important: bash, not sh
count=0
while IFS= read -r x; do
  echo "Read a line: <$x>" >&2
  (( ++count ))
done < <(egrep '^$' txtfile)
echo "Read $count lines" >&2
```